# change all values of pandas dataframe based on condition?

Tags: pandas

Consider the following example pandas dataframe,

```
     col1  col2 col3
0     1     3    9
1     2     4    0
```

how can I take all values larger than 0.5 and convert them into 1 without a for loop? In this toy example, the resulting dataframe should be

```
     col1  col2 col3
0     1     1    1
1     1     1    0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

IIUC `mask`

```
df=df.mask(df>0.5,1)
df
Out[605]: 
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     1     1
1     1     1     0
```

Answer (score 2):

Or:

```
(df>.5).mul(1)
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2 col3
0    1    1    1
1    1    1    0
```

Faster:

```
pd.DataFrame((df.values>.5), index=df.index, columns=df.columns, dtype=np.int)
```

## Timings

```
%timeit df.mask(df>0.5,1)
```

> 100 loops, best of 3: 2.26 ms per loop

```
%timeit (df>.5).mul(1)
```

> 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.03 ms per loop

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame((df.values>.5), index=df.index, columns=df.columns, dtype=np.int)
```

> 10000 loops, best of 3: 163 µs per loop

Comment: Umm... what about just: `df[df > 0.5] = 1` ?

Comment: @JonClements I got `100 loops, best of 3: 2.13 ms per loop`  But the code is condensed.

Comment: How about he have 0.04

Answer (score 1):

Just another option:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x>0.5 else 0)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     1     1
1     1     1     0
```