# transform function on all columns of dataframe

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a dataframe `df` and I am trying to apply a function to each of the cells. According to the [documentation](https://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/man/split_apply_combine/) I should use the `transform` function.

The function should be applied to each column so I use `[:]` as a selector for all columns

```
transform(
    df, [:] .=> ByRow(x -> (if (x > 1) x else zero(Float64) end)) .=> [:]
)
```

but it yields an exception

```
ArgumentError: Unrecognized column selector: Colon() => (DataFrames.ByRow{Main.workspace293.var"#1#2"}(Main.workspace293.var"#1#2"()) => Colon())
```

although when I am using a single column, it works fine

```
transform(
    df, [:K0] .=> ByRow(x -> (if (x > 1) x else zero(Float64) end)) .=> [:K0]
)
```

Comment: can't you do something as simple as :  df=df.mask(df<=1,0)

Comment: you can also look into. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49496389/change-all-values-of-pandas-dataframe-based-on-condition

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change all values of pandas dataframe based on condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49496389/change-all-values-of-pandas-dataframe-based-on-condition)

Comment: @JoeFerndz I believe those are python-related questions, I am working in Julia :)

Comment: my bad, i didnt see Julia. Happy to learn new things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is to use broadcasting:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(2*rand(4,3), [:x1, :x2, :x3])
4×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ x1        │ x2       │ x3       │
│     │ Float64   │ Float64  │ Float64  │
├─────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.945879  │ 1.59742  │ 0.882428 │
│ 2   │ 0.0963367 │ 0.400404 │ 0.599865 │
│ 3   │ 1.23356   │ 0.807691 │ 0.547917 │
│ 4   │ 0.756098  │ 0.595673 │ 0.29678  │

julia> @. ifelse(df > 1, df, 0.0)
4×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ x1      │ x2      │ x3      │
│     │ Float64 │ Float64 │ Float64 │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.0     │ 1.59742 │ 0.0     │
│ 2   │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │
│ 3   │ 1.23356 │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │
│ 4   │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │
```

you can also `transform` for it if you prefer:

```
julia> transform(df, names(df) .=> ByRow(x -> ifelse(x>1, x, 0.0)) .=> names(df))
4×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ x1      │ x2      │ x3      │
│     │ Float64 │ Float64 │ Float64 │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.0     │ 1.59742 │ 0.0     │
│ 2   │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │
│ 3   │ 1.23356 │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │
│ 4   │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │
```

Also looking at the linked pandas solution DataFrames.jl seems faster in this case:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(2*rand(2,3), [:x1, :x2, :x3])
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x1       x2       x3       
     │ Float64  Float64  Float64  
─────┼────────────────────────────
   1 │ 1.48781  1.20332  1.08071
   2 │ 1.55462  1.66393  0.363993

julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime @. ifelse($df > 1, $df, 0.0)
  6.252 μs (58 allocations: 3.89 KiB)
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x1       x2       x3      
     │ Float64  Float64  Float64 
─────┼───────────────────────────
   1 │ 1.48781  1.20332  1.08071
   2 │ 1.55462  1.66393  0.0
```

(in pandas for 2x3 data frame it was ranging from 163 µs to 2.26 ms)